# Phonegap - continuous audio playback not working when the app is in background mode

Tags: android, ios, html, audio, cordova

I have built an audio streaming application for iOS and Android using Phonegap. I have used HTML5 Audio API to play audio files. The audio is being streamed from a PHP server.

When i try to play a song, it is playing fine when the application is in foreground and background/locked.

When i try to play a list of songs, the current song is playing till the end but the next song is not playing. This is working fine when the app is in foreground and not working when the app is in background/locked state.

**Detailed Scenario:**

Select a song from the playlist. The song is being played.

Push the application to background/lock the device. The current song is still playing till it ends.

While the app is in background, once the current song ends the next song is retrieved from the server. But it is not playing.

Now when i bring the app to the foreground, it immediately starts playing without even buffering. This is because that the song is already served from the server and buffered when it was in background.

**Platforms and the issue:** iOS (background & locked) & Android (background mode only. works fine in locked state)

I have done my research on this problem and all i could find was few solutions for native audio players. Have anyone solved this?

Comment: Did you every find a solution for this?